# Can I connect an Android phone to a DSL Modem via USB?

Tags: wi-fi

Is it possible to connect my phone directly to a DSL line (Via USB) and then use tethering features to make my phone behave as a Wireless Router ?

Comment: I'd imagine something like this may be possible with a device that has OTG Support. However, I don't know if Android is capable of establishing a connection over anything other than Cellular or WiFi in the first place. Any solution would likely be very unwieldly and difficult to implement.

Comment: Sounds like a combination of [tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering) and [wifi-hotspot]. Have you checked those tags, or maybe a [combined search](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[wifi-hotspot]+tether+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1)?

Comment: yep but no result ,how to transfer adsl connection to mobile phone,may be like @dotVezz mention above via OTG usb

Comment: I  actually means transfering phone line  to mobile phone directlly via usb or other stuff and use mobile phone like a adsl modem.

Comment: yes I am able to find a adapter whick is phone line-usb converter.now the basic question I wanna transfer data via usb to my phone.but can device understand those data coming.http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/1351903876/Support_10_100_1000Mbp_usb3_0.html?s=p

Comment: umm,this rj45 jack but I need rj11 jack.

Comment: http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/668612667/Hot_sale_high_quality_rj11_to.html   this one is okey for me